# How can I add a search bar to search text on .html page

Tags: php, html, list, search

I know I can add this:

```
<form>
  Search Google:
  <input type="search" name="googlesearch">
</form>
```

But that will only allow me to search google.

I want people to be able to search there names on this list.
http://graphicambi.tk/onlineemployees.html

How can I do this?

ALSO

I cant figure out where to place 
 too...

here is a part of my code:

```
    } 

$sql = "SELECT userID, users_name, usertype, status FROM tbluseraccounts";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($row["status"] == "Online"){
        $tcolor = "green";
    }
    elseif($row["status"] == "Offline"){
        $tcolor = "red";
    }
        echo "<br>ID: " . $row["userID"]. " <br> Name: " . $row["users_name"]. " <br> Account Type: " . $row["usertype"]. " <br> Status: <font color='".$tcolor."'>" . $row["status"]. "</font><br>";
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}
```

Where is says:

```
echo "<br>ID: " . $row["userID"]. " <br> Name: " . $row["users_name"]. " <br> Account Type: " . $row["usertype"]. " <br> Status: <font color='".$tcolor."'>" . $row["status"]. "</font><br>";
```

I want to create that border going around there so when you go on this site http://graphicambi.tk/onlineemployees.html there will be a black border around each account name

Thank you.

Comment: You do know they can using their browser's ctrl+f find

Comment: Yes. Just figured id try to make it easier for them lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your orders are in a DB so you can use a simple search form.

Something like this :

```
<FORM method="POST" action="search.php">
    <INPUT type="text" name="search">
    <INPUT type="submit">
</FORM>
```

In your search.php file :

```
$sql = "SELECT userID, users_name, usertype, status FROM tbluseraccounts WHERE users_name LIKE %$_POST['search']%";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($row["status"] == "Online"){
        $tcolor = "green";
    }
    elseif($row["status"] == "Offline"){
        $tcolor = "red";
    }
        echo "<br>ID: " . $row["userID"]. " <br> Name: " . $row["users_name"]. " <br> Account Type: " . $row["usertype"]. " <br> Status: <font color='".$tcolor."'>" . $row["status"]. "</font><br>";
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}
```